# Как добавить блок span к раскрывающемуся пункту меню в WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть собранное в админке меню. Так же есть небольшой класс, суть которого добавлять к ul определенный класс.

```
class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array()) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">\n";
    }
}
```

Необходимо преобразовать пункты меню, имеющие подменю следующим образом: 
Вместо

```
<li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a>ссылка</a>
</li>
```

вывести

```
<li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a>ссылка <span>что-то тут</span></a>
</li>
```

подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: а где код, в котором у вас происходит добавление тега `<li>`?

Comment: в стандартном Walker

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено:
Нужно дополнить вышепредставленный класс My_Walker_Nav_Menu следующим образом:

```
class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array()) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">\n";
    }

    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        // назначаем классы li-элементу и выводим его
        $class_names = join( ' ', $item->classes );
        $class_names = ' class="' .esc_attr( $class_names ). '"';
        $output.= '<li id="menu-item-' . $item->ID . '"' .$class_names. '>';

        // назначаем атрибуты a-элементу
        $attributes.= !empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' .esc_attr($item->url). '"' : '';
        $item_output = $args->before;

        // проверяем, есть ли класс menu-item-has-children и, если есть, модифицируем ссылку
        if (strpos($class_names, 'menu-item-has-children')) 
            $item_output.= '<a'. $attributes .'>'.$item->title.'<span></span></a>';
        else 
            $item_output.= '<a'. $attributes .'>'.$item->title.'</a>';

        // заканчиваем вывод элемента
        $item_output.= $args->after;
        $output.= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```